# How much is appropriate for an emergency fund?

Tags: banking, emergency-fund

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [As a general rule, how much in “liquid” emergency savings should I have?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83/as-a-general-rule-how-much-in-liquid-emergency-savings-should-i-have)

How can one calculate how much emergency fund should one put away? What factors? How to decide how much should an emergency fund should be?